# jQuery error: "this.rc is not a function" (e.g. with OpenLayers on resize)

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

got this trying to attach a resize event:

```
$( '.ui-resizable' ).resize( map.updateSize )  // causes the error "this.rc is not a function"
```

using OpenLayers 3.3.0 and jQuery 1.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but the **following** finally **did the trick**:

```
$( '.ui-resizable' ).resize( function(){ map.updateSize(); } )
```

So I guess the `map.updateSize` is somehow an "*improper function*" for jQuery, now wrapped within some anonymous function.